# How can I alter a call that's in progress with Twilio & NodeJs

Tags: node.js, twilio

Here are the steps that I'd like to accomplish:

1. Call, and eventually text, my Twilio number
2. Gather a number to call.
3. Create and move my current call into a conference call.
4. Call the gathered number.
5. Add the called number into the conference with me.

Currently I can call my Twilio number, gather a number to be called, create a conference call - but where I'm getting lost is calling the gathered number as well as adding them into the conference I created.

```js
app.post('/call', function(req, res) {

  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  res.type('text/xml');

  if (req.body.From === '+15555555555) {
    twiml.gather({
      action: '/call/initiate',
      finishOnKey: '#',
      numDigits: '10',
      timeout: '5'
    }, function() {
      this.say('Enter your number', {
        voice: 'man'
      });
    });

  }
  else {

    twiml.redirect(VOICEMAIL_TWIMLET_OF_CHOICE);

  }

  res.send(twiml.toString());

});

// Initiate a call from text
app.post('/call/initiate', function(req, res) {
  // Create new Twiml response
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  // Phone number to call and add to conference
  var to = req.body.Digits;

  // Create random conference name
  var conferenceName = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000).toString();

  // Add myself to the conference call
  twiml.dial((node) => {
    node.conference(conferenceName, {
      startConferenceOnEnter: true,
      record: true,
      beep: 'true'
    });
  });

  // Redirect twiml to a new url
  // Send conferenceName & Number
  twiml.redirect('/join_conference?id=' + conferenceName + '&number=' + to);

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});

// Call and add caller to conference
app.post('/join_conference', (req, res) => {

  var conferenceName = req.query.id;
  var to = '+1' + req.query.number;

  // Create new Twiml response
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

  // Call and add user to conference call
  twiml.dial(to, (node) => {
    node.conference(conferenceName, {
      startConferenceOnEnter: true,
    });
  });

  console.log('call called');

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

After I enter the digits and hit the `finishOnKey` I automatically hear the waiting music. However, at that point - the app just hangs and a call isn't placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue is that the TwiML you return to your `/call/initiate` endpoint is just for the first leg of your call, you can't create another call leg with TwiML alone.

However, you can use the [Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) to [generate the second leg of the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) within the same request. Here's an updated endpoint that you can use instead:

```
app.post('/call/initiate', function(req, res) {
  // Create new Twiml response
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  // Phone number to call and add to conference
  var to = req.body.Digits;

  // Create random conference name
  var conferenceName = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000).toString();

  // Add myself to the conference call
  twiml.dial((node) => {
    node.conference(conferenceName, {
      startConferenceOnEnter: true,
      record: true,
      beep: 'true'
    });
  });

  // Make call to the other party
  // Send conferenceName as part of the URL
  var client = new twilio(YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN);
  client.calls.create({
    from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
    to: '+1' + to,
    url: 'https://example.com/join_conference?id=' + conferenceName
  });

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Then your '/join_conference' endpoint need only dial the caller into the conference room, like so:

```
app.post('/join_conference', (req, res) => {

  var conferenceName = req.query.id;

  // Create new Twiml response
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

  // Call and add user to conference call
  twiml.dial((node) => {
    node.conference(conferenceName, {
      startConferenceOnEnter: true,
    });
  });

  console.log('call called');

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

*Edit:* The comment said it still wasn't calling the other party. Let's take a look more closely at the command to call the other side. The call to create will return a Promise, so we can see what happens and whether it is succeeding or failing (and why).

```
  var client = new twilio(YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN);
  client.calls.create({
    from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
    to: '+1' + to,
    url: 'http://example.com/join_conference?id=' + conferenceName
  }).then(function(call) {
    console.log(call.sid);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error("Something went wrong creating the call.");
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Try updating the code to that and see what happens. If there is an error, I'm sure it will help you solve this.

Comment: I tried those changes to no success. The process is still hanging at '/call/initiate'. Doesn't seem to make the call to the second party at all and from logs I can see it never hits the 'join_conference' endpoint.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I'd try to catch any errors from the call generation, that might show up what is going on.

Comment: Thank you - I should've known to do that. I've updated the code to include the error handling. Now I see that my URL is invalid. (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21205). I looked through my Twilio dashboard and didn't see the spot where I need to set a handled for that type of request.

Comment: I haven't helped there with my example. I've edited it now, but when you create a call you need to include the full URL, not just the path. What do you mean by "set a handled for that type of request"?

Comment: I thought I needed to set a URL within the Twilio dashboard to handle a post request coming from a call in progress, I was wrong. As it stands, the call seems to be succeeding however, the application isn't redirecting to 'join_conference' to add the other caller. But I am getting the SID logged in the console.

Comment: It shouldn't redirect, the second call should hit /join_conference as it's initial webhook. Is this solved then? If so, could you mark the answer as correct so that others can see that it helped. Thanks!